# Configure latexmk to work recursively with files living in different folders

Tags: latexmk, xr

This is a follow up on [How to configure latexmk to work recursively? (PDF Thumbnails)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/how-to-configure-latexmk-to-work-recursively-pdf-thumbnails) and [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references).

Let me first say what I'm trying to achieve. I have a latex project that consists of multiple files, eg. `/myproj/main.tex`, `/myproj/a/a.tex`, `/myproj/b/b.tex`, where `main.tex` depends on `a.tex` and `a.tex` depends on `b.tex`. And by "depends on", I mean I'm using the package `xr` to do some cross-referencing between these files via `\externaldocument`. For example, in `a.tex`, I would have `\externaldocument{../b/b.tex}`. My goal is to set up latexmk in such a way that makes it recompile `main.tex` when `b.tex` changes.

The first answer of [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references) provides a way to notify latexmk about the dependency relation between the files by printing something to stdout which latexmk will capture. Then, the first answer of [How to configure latexmk to work recursively? (PDF Thumbnails)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/how-to-configure-latexmk-to-work-recursively-pdf-thumbnails) provides a way to make latexmk run recursively. However, as far as I can see, when files are placed in different directories, it fails for two reasons:

1. Subsequent runs of latexmk (which I invoke via `latexmk -cd`) don't have access to the same `.latexmkr` anymore since now, it's in a different directory.
2. `Latexmk` records `../b/b.tex` as the dependency for `main.tex`, which does not make sense, since the path `../b/b.tex` is relative to `a/a.tex` rather than to `main.tex`.

To fix 1., I hacked `.latexmkrc` so that it copies a version of `.latexmkrc` everywhere it goes (and clean up later). It's not the best solution, but it works in the sense that the first time I call `latexmk`, it compiles everything.

However, `latexmk` still fails to detect changes to `b/b.tex`, and I think it's due to 2. I've tried to modify [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references) so that absolute path is expanded from the relative path and printed out, but didn't have that much success.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help, either with fixing problem 2 mentioned above or with a completely new solution altogether.

Thanks!